# How can I programmatically delete an App Bundle on device

Tags: android

While developing my Android App Bundle app, and loading it onto a device using commands from the bundletool jar:

C:\Dev\ADev>SET PATH="C:/jdk-12.0.2";%PATH%&&java -jar "C:/bundletool-
master/bundletool-all-1.8.2.jar" build-apks --
bundle="C:/Android/Dev/G_GameNew/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab" --
output="C:/Android/Dev/G_GameNew/output.apks" --connected-device --overwrite --verbose

C:\Dev\ADev>SET PATH="C:/jdk-12.0.2";%PATH%&&java -jar "C:/bundletool-
master/bundletool-all-1.8.2.jar" install-apks --
apks="C:/Android/Dev/G_GameNew/output.apks"

I've noticed that the only way to be sure that it's properly removed before installing the latest code is to physically go on the device, select Apps, and do an Uninstall.
If you try to use 'adb uninstall' it doesn't Uninstall it properly, and the new code isn't going to work like from manually doing an Uninstall.

If you use adb, it will act like it was successful, but it seems like it's not all the way gone.

So my question is how can you programmatically uninstall an installed App Bundle properly?

Note, I'm not using Android Studio, I'm building everything from the command line.
And I'm using Windows.

UPDATE: I confirmed that after I made a change in the code, built the App Bundle, then used 'adb uninstall' to uninstall the previous version and used the above to load the new code, the change didn't happen when run.

Then I manually Uninstalled it from the device, built it and installed it using the above, and the changed code executed.

Thanks!